# CAML Query to retrieve announcement items in descending order based on ID # - Not Working

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-enterprise, caml-query

```
spQuery.Query = "
   <OrderBy>  <FieldRef Name='ID' Descending='True'/>   </OrderBy>
   <Where> <Eq> <FieldRef Name='Title' /> 
   <Value Type='Text'></Value> </Eq>  
   </Where>";
```

What is wrong with this?
It still only returns the announcements in the same order as they were added.
Thanks

Comment: Why do you use <Where> when you only want to order it.

Comment: I think he is trying to return it, but he should be using <ViewFields>.

Comment: Use [U2U Caml builder](http://www.u2u.be/res/tools/camlquerybuilder.aspx) to test your query. It is helpful tool if your query does not work. )

Comment: <View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='False'/></OrderBy></Query><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title'/></ViewFields><RowLimit>5</RowLimit></View>    This works great when I test it in the U2U Query builder bu tjust refuses to work when I use it on my ascx.cs page   Strange!

Comment: try to use spQuery.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='False'/></OrderBy>" and spQuery.ViewFields="<FieldRef Name='Title'"/>

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms442728.aspx) there's no such an attribute on FieldRef as "Descending" - there is an "Ascending" one:

```
<FieldRef
  Alias = "Text"
  Ascending = "TRUE" | "FALSE"
  CreateURL = "Text"
  DisplayName = "Text"
  Explicit = "TRUE" | "FALSE"    Format = "Text"
  ID = "Text"
  Key = "Text"  List = “Text”
  Name = "Text"
  RefType = "Text"
  ShowField = "Text"
  TextOnly = "TRUE" | "FALSE"
  Type = "Text">
</FieldRef>
```

Comment: So if I would to specify ascending = 'False' it would actually display items in descending order (ID #'s)?

Comment: Yes Ascending="FALSE" is the right way to specify descending

Comment: Well I used the same code with ascending = 'True' and it doesnt make any difference. Am I missing something?

Comment: You're need to set Ascending = "FALSE" - not TRUE.

Comment: My fault. I did set the ascending to false. Still the same result.

Answer (score 7):

Well, first thing is your OrderBy tags need to be contained within a Query tag. Second, I've never used Descending, just Ascending = 'False'.

Check out this example CAML query:

```
 <View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Created' Ascending='True'></FieldRef>
 </OrderBy></Query><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title'/><FieldRef Name='Body'/>
 <FieldRef Name='Created'/></ViewFields></View>
```

Comment: SPQuery spQuery = new SPQuery();
     spQuery.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID'   Ascending='False'/></OrderBy><Where> <Eq> <FieldRef   Name='Title' /> <Value Type='Text'></Value> </Eq> </Where>";
      spQuery.Query = "";
      spQuery.RowLimit = 5;

Comment: Here is some context so you can take a look at what I have

Comment: SPQuery spQuery = new SPQuery(); spQuery.Query = "<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='False'/></OrderBy></Query><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title'/></ViewFields><RowLimit>5</RowLimit></View>";

Comment: For one, you are clearing the query entirely by setting it to a blank string after you set it to your first query.

Comment: I did remove spQuery.Query = ""; and tried using the code you provided but it still yields the same result. I know that the data is being pulled right as when I add items to my list the web part does render the changes.

Comment: However, the row limit is not being picked up now.

Comment: http://sharepointmagazine.net/articles/writing-caml-queries-for-retrieving-list-items-from-a-sharepoint-list

Comment: <View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='False'/></OrderBy></Query><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title'/></ViewFields><RowLimit>5</RowLimit></View>    This works great when I test it in the U2U Query builder bu tjust refuses to work when I use it on my ascx.cs page   Strange!

Answer (score 1):

CAML Query in this case is not necessary. Because you can order the list with your View, check this please:

```
SPList list = web.Lists[listName];
SPView view = list.DefaultView;
SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(view);
```

In this code, I have DESCENDING order by ID in my list default view.

Answer (score 0):

For retrieving announcement items in descending order based on ID you should only need to use OrderBy query:

```
 spQuery.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='FALSE'/></OrderBy>";
```